# Installing ARM Development Studio on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: arm

I'd like to install an ARM Development Studio environment on Ubuntu 12.10. I Googled it, but didn't find anything useful. Can anyone help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ARM DS-5™ toolchain installer is available for Windows 32/64-bit, Linux 64-bit and Linux 32-bit hosts. you need to visit [ARM Development Studio download page](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/ds-5/ds-5-downloads.php) sign-up and download the software with 1 month free licence.